# How to fit two HTML forms in a box where one form has to be an L-shape

Tags: html, forms

So, I've got a requirement to have two forms in a dialog, where there are four sections.

I'll attach an image.

[image: concept]

I want the first form to contain the orange blocks, and the second form to contain only the green block.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Forms are natively blocks, so that means that if I try, the green block will be put below the bottom-left block, which is now what I want.

Comment: Im not use what you mean by forms, you mean a physically form that you will in or just the shape of the 'blocks'?

Comment: If so, like this - https://jsfiddle.net/4c6nf6wk/

Answer (score 2):

In short

```css
.outer {
  width: 224px;
}
.inset {
  float: left;
  margin: 6px;
  padding: 6px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
}
.outset {
  float: left;
  margin: 6px;
  padding: 6px;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer" style="width:448px;">
  <form action="login.php" method="post">
    <div class="outer" style="float: left;">
      <div class="outset" style="height: 100px;">Top Left
        <input type="text" name="user">
      </div>
      <div class="outset" style="height: 50px;">Bottom Left
        <input type="password" name="password">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer" style="float: left;">
      <div class="outset" style="height: 50px;">Top Right
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <form action="register.php" method="post">
    <div class="inset" style="height: 100px;">Bottom right
      <input type="text" name="user">
      <input type="password" name="password">
      <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```